# Automatically Determine Credit Card Type

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically determine the credit card type for magento credit cards forms instead of having the customer manually pick it.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3):

There's a great post about this on stackoverflow. You can check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number.

The two post important excerpts:

> Visa: `^4[0-9]{6,}$` Visa card numbers start with a 4.
>
> MasterCard: `^5[1-5][0-9]{5,}$` MasterCard numbers start with the
>   numbers 51 through 55, but this will only detect MasterCard credit
>   cards; there are other cards issued using the MasterCard system that
>   do not fall into this IIN range.
>
> American Express: `^3[47][0-9]{5,}$` American Express card numbers
>   start with 34 or 37.
>
> Diners Club: `^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{4,}$` Diners Club card
>   numbers begin with 300 through 305, 36 or 38. There are Diners Club
>   cards that begin with 5 and have 16 digits. These are a joint venture
>   between Diners Club and MasterCard, and should be processed like a
>   MasterCard.
>
> Discover: `^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3,}$` Discover card numbers begin
>   with 6011 or 65.
>
> JCB: `^(?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{3,}$` JCB cards begin with 2131,
>   1800 or 35.

And a full class actually

```
class CreditcardType
    {
   public static $creditcardTypes = array(
            array('Name'=>'American Express','cardLength'=>array(15),'cardPrefix'=>array('34', '37'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Maestro','cardLength'=>array(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19),'cardPrefix'=>array('5018', '5020', '5038', '6304', '6759', '6761', '6763'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Mastercard','cardLength'=>array(16),'cardPrefix'=>array('51', '52', '53', '54', '55'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Visa','cardLength'=>array(13,16),'cardPrefix'=>array('4'))
            ,array('Name'=>'JCB','cardLength'=>array(16),'cardPrefix'=>array('3528', '3529', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Discover','cardLength'=>array(16),'cardPrefix'=>array('6011', '622126', '622127', '622128', '622129', '62213',
                                        '62214', '62215', '62216', '62217', '62218', '62219',
                                        '6222', '6223', '6224', '6225', '6226', '6227', '6228',
                                        '62290', '62291', '622920', '622921', '622922', '622923',
                                        '622924', '622925', '644', '645', '646', '647', '648',
                                        '649', '65'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Solo','cardLength'=>array(16, 18, 19),'cardPrefix'=>array('6334', '6767'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Unionpay','cardLength'=>array(16, 17, 18, 19),'cardPrefix'=>array('622126', '622127', '622128', '622129', '62213', '62214',
                                        '62215', '62216', '62217', '62218', '62219', '6222', '6223',
                                        '6224', '6225', '6226', '6227', '6228', '62290', '62291',
                                        '622920', '622921', '622922', '622923', '622924', '622925'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Diners Club','cardLength'=>array(14),'cardPrefix'=>array('300', '301', '302', '303', '304', '305', '36'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Diners Club US','cardLength'=>array(16),'cardPrefix'=>array('54', '55'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Diners Club Carte Blanche','cardLength'=>array(14),'cardPrefix'=>array('300','305'))
            ,array('Name'=>'Laser','cardLength'=>array(16, 17, 18, 19),'cardPrefix'=>array('6304', '6706', '6771', '6709'))
    );     
        private function __construct() {}    
        public static function getType($CCNumber)
        {
            $CCNumber= trim($CCNumber);
            $type='Unknown';
            foreach (CreditcardType::$creditcardTypes as $card){
                if (! in_array(strlen($CCNumber),$card['cardLength'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $prefixes = '/^('.implode('|',$card['cardPrefix']).')/';            
                if(preg_match($prefixes,$CCNumber) == 1 ){
                    $type= $card['Name'];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks how would you add this to the cc.phtml?

Comment: I would probably go with a little javascript function. That was also in one of the answers in the link. Use an onchange even on the input to trigger it. Check out this article also: http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/auto-detecting-credit-card-type/

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you little . So please check this

[magento auto selected credit card type](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/magento-auto-selected-credit-card-type/)